# Port forwarding through a router and a VPN work separately, but not together

Tags: networking, router, vpn, iptables, wireguard

I have a router from my ISP (Orange Funbox 2.0). In it, I forwarded port 6568 to my Raspberry Pi, which runs a Wireguard VPN. On the server, I set up port forwarding to the end device (my phone) with

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -4 -p tcp --dport 6568 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2:6567
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -4 -p udp --dport 6568 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.2:6567
```

[Here's a diagram of the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY5q9.png)

I set up an HTTP server on the phone, listening on port 6567, and connected it to the VPN. Connecting from Home PC to `192.168.1.4:6568` shows that the connection works, and a web page is displayed. Connecting from outside my home network (ReqBin in the diagram) to the HTTP server on the Pi works as well. However, trying to reach the Phone (through the forwarded port on the router and then the VPN) from the outside network does not work. Neither Home PC, nor ReqBin can achieve a connection when going through the Home Router. `iptables` counters show that the packets reach the server, and are processed correctly. Logs on the phone show no connections.

Where do the packets disappear?

Comment: I do not know your setup but I certainly use VPN and have done for a long time. You do not need port forwarding with VPN. Just set up your remote and local subnets to encompass the machines you wish to see / access.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "encompass the machines you wish to see / access". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Look in the VPN setups for Remote and Local subnets. That is what I was referring to.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Do you mean giving the device connecting to the VPN an address in the subnet that my home network works with?

Comment: Do you mean giving the device connecting to the VPN an address in the subnet that my home network works with   ...   Yes, I think that is correct. I would normally provide the local subnet group at each end of the VPN a complete local subnet at each end.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying right, you misunderstood my question. There is no subnet on the other side of the VPN, there's just a single device.

Comment: Just use VPN then and not port forwarding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127638/discussion-between-adamski234-and-john).

Comment: Well, do your home PC or router even have route for `192.168.2.0/24` with the VPN server / pi's LAN IP as gateway? (Or, what exactly do you mean by `trying to reach the Phone` anyway?)

Comment: If they don't have route for the VPN subnet, the packets probably went to your ISP (your router's default gateway) where it got dropped or so.

Comment: Does the router need to have a route to 192.168.2.0/24? I thought that this wasn't needed when doing forwarding. `trying to reach the Phone` means connecting to the router on the forwarded port (`my.domain:6568`)

Comment: *Port forwarding* (destination NAT) needs proper routing and *IP forwarding* to work. Besides, what does you phone have to do with your setup? Just like what you draw, your phone is irrelevant / unrelated to the whole thing except being in the same LAN/subnet as the Pi. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ahh, you mean you are trying to do two layers of destination NAT? Like `Public/WAN IP:6568 -> 192.168.1.4:6568 -> 192.168.2.2:6567`? First of all, have you even configured the outer layer DNAT on the router? Besides, this approach is not exactly a decent way AFAIK. I don't have much experience with such setup to tell whether it is doomed to fail / failure-prone though.

Comment: My goal is to be able to use my phone as a server when I'm not at home. As in, I set up an HTTP/FTP/whatever server on my phone, connect it to the VPN and make it accessible through my.domain.com. I can't directly forward to my phone, since it's not in the network I can manage. So, since I already had a VPN, I figured that I could make it work by forwarding a port through the VPN server to the phone. Which works, however it breaks when there are two forwards.

Comment: If you are DNAT'ing `Public/WAN IP:some port` from the router "directly" to `192.168.2.2:6567`, the router will need to know `192.168.1.4` is the gateway for `192.168.2.0/24` (or just `192.168.2.2`).

Comment: "Directly" refers to the IP/L3 network in the scope of concern, not the cellular network or wifi network the phone is connected to.

Comment: I'm not NATing to `192.168.2.2`. My router doesn't even allow me to input an IP outside of its subnet. I NAT to `192.168.1.4` (Pi running the VPN) on which I also forward port 6568 to `192.168.2.2:6567`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127710/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-adamski234).